# YAML mapping values are not allowed here - possible indentation issue?

Tags: yaml, circleci

So I am trying to learn CircleCI and been following the getting started tutorial: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/getting-started/

config.yml:

```
version: 2
 jobs:
   one:
     docker:
       - image: circleci/ruby:2.4.1
     steps:
       - checkout
       - run: echo "A first hello"
       - run: sleep 25
   two:
     docker:
       - image: circleci/ruby:2.4.1
     steps:
       - checkout
       - run: echo "A more familiar hi"
       - run: sleep 15
 workflows:
   version: 2
   one_and_two:
     jobs:
       - one
       - two
```

This returns

```
Error: Unable to parse YAML
mapping values are not allowed here
 in 'string', line 2, column 6:
     jobs:
         ^
```

I don't understand the problem. From the documentation, it appears that it is the correct indentation level. So what is the source of this error, exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation shows clearly that `version` and `jobs` must be on the same indentation level. If you indent `jobs` more, you make it part of the scalar `2`.

This would be valid YAML:

```
version: 2
 jobs
```

and equalivalent to:

```
version: 2 jobs
```

However, the `:` after `jobs` makes it invalid since YAML does not allow implicit keys  to be multi-line (`version:` would be a proper implicit key).

To fix the error, simply do not indent `jobs` more than `version`.

Comment: I see this was the problem, thank you. It seems it added this indentation when I copy pasted and didnt know it was a problem!